# Check If String Exists in Text Field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a basic form which contains a text field like this:

[image: My Basic Form]

But I want to control if exist any predefined word like "Mickey", If it does not exist, I want to block submitting, like validations in registration forms. This predefined word can be anywhere in textfield like "MickeyMouse" or "MouseMickey" or "MyMickeymouse".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use HTML5 form validation. Simply make the field `required` and give it a `pattern`. No JS required (although you might choose a [polyfill](http://html5please.com/#polyfill) for old browsers).

Try and submit this form without matching the pattern:

```html
<form>
    <input name="myInput" 
           required="required" 
           placeholder="Must contain Mickey" 
           pattern=".*Mickey.*" 
           title="It must contain Mickey somewhere."
    />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Also: [Untested example with basic JS fallback](http://jsfiddle.net/1tx2wr9z/)

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" id="button" class="button" onclick="return submitcheck();" />
```

**Script**

```
function submitcheck() {
    if(document.getElementById("textField").value.indexOf("Mickey") > -1) {
         return true;
    } else {
         return false;
    }
}
```

If n is not -1 then Mickey was in the string.

Comment: What is `textfield` supposed to be? A DOM element, as its name seems to suggest?

Comment: Fair enough, I wasn't being specific enough

Comment: Then, how can I block submitting ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a 'text field' DOM element somewhere:

```
if($(<textfield>).val().indexOf($(<inputID>).val()) > -1){
    //things to be done if 'Mickey' present
}
```

You can do this validation on click of the submit button.