# Validation form to check whether a word exists or not in the form field

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an original form like this:

```
   <tr>
    <td>URL</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="url" placeholder="Enter Your Sitename URL" size="100" required></td>
   </tr>
```

and I want if a user fills in the URL column, they must write **http://** or **https://** at the beginning of the URL.

If they don't write it down there will be an alert and cannot be processed.

I already follow the [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28173210/check-if-string-exists-in-text-field), but I can not submit my form.

Here is my code after I follow the link:

```
   <tr>
    <td>URL</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="url" placeholder="Enter the url of your site using http:// or https:// at the beginning" pattern="^http:// || ^https://" title="The column must begin with http:// or https://"  size="100" required></td>
   </tr>
```

and here is the image:
[image]

So, how to create form validation to check the word at the beginning of the column?

Comment: Can't you just use the [`<input type="url">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/url)

Comment: oh, I just know there is url in input type. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in so many ways.

**Js:**

```js
function IsOk(form){

  const url = document.getElementById('url').value;

  if(url.includes("http://") || url.includes("https://")){
    form.submit();
  }else{
       alert('You must insert http:// or https://');
       return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form  method="post" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();IsOk(this);">
<input type="text" name="url" id="url" placeholder="Enter Your Sitename URL" size="100" required>
<button type="submit">click me</button>
</form>
```

You can use sweetalert for improve alert.

**Html:**

Set `<input type="url">` like:

```html
<form  method="post">
<input type="url" name="url" id="url" pattern="https://.*" placeholder="Enter Your Sitename URL" size="100" required>
<button type="submit">click me</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved a problem with simply checking that the form field has data when all the other solutions failed.